# Oversight in mikvah preparation; is her husband guilty?

Tags: reward-punishment, korban, mikvah-ritual-bath, motzi-yedei-chovato, shlichus-agency

Ordinarily, if we make an honest mistake in our efforts to do a mitzvah--or we do an inadvertent aveira--we are, at least to some extent, forgiven. In any case, our liability, and our obligation to bring a korban, etc., are less than they would be for a transgression with full intention.

Is this equally true in a case where a second party is involved--for instance, if a woman overlooked a chatzitzah for mikvah (presumably the mikvah attendant also overlooked it)? Is her husband, who trusts her, responsible for a kareis-level sin if he sleeps with her, or only for much less?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66120/discussion-on-question-by-sah-oversight-in-mikvah-preparation-is-her-husband-gu).